# Смена email в git config

Tags: git, github

На своем гитхабе я сменил почту. Теперь нужно обновить почту в терминале, чтобы осуществлять комиты по правильному адресу.

Написав:

```
git config user.email
```

Я получаю старый email

Как изменить на новый?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте Ваш адрес после. Используйте кавычки не обязательно, но лишним не будет.

```
git config user.email "new@mail.ru"
```

Comment: Спасибо, только нужно `--global` добавить и изменится. `git config --global user.email "new@mail.ru"`

Comment: С глобал меняется для всех проектов, а без глобал только для текущего.

Comment: @Эникейщик Такой вопрос, как переписать все прошлые комиты со старой почты на новую? А то они перестали отображаться из-за смены почты.

Comment: Для этого придется переписывать всю историю. Если есть готовность, то смотрите [на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)

Comment: @Эникейщик Помогло! Спасибо)